# Mongodb: Apply group in a single collection with multiple relations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs, database

Example: A Collection name is `Account` which is having categories and upvotes and downvotes. Upvotes and downvotes are basically feeds of categories. The structure of the Collection is as follows:

```
{
    "id": "585a2f2735cc577c178bda2b",
    "category_ids": [
        "5857e65c950cfd241818abc3",
        "5857e92f950cfd241818abd0",
        "5857e957950cfd241818abd2",
        "5857f03f950cfd241818abd5"
    ],
    "upVotes": [
        {
            "id": "585a6ccc055f93cbb10bd179",
            "name": "career feed",
            "category_ids": [
                "5857e65c950cfd241818abc3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5860bc714b7b3a400ef96d2a",
            "name": "Treasurers and Controllers",
            "category_ids": [
                "5857e957950cfd241818abd2"
            ]
         }
    ],
    "downVotes": [
        {
            "id": "585a8fbb416ecf300c6ea969",
            "name": "testinggggg",
            "category_ids": [
                "5857f03f950cfd241818abd5",
                "5857f07c950cfd241818abd6"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "585a8406354db7d811f9a405",
            "name": "feeds5",
            "category_ids": [
                "5857e957950cfd241818abd2",
                "5857f07c950cfd241818abd6"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to show downvotes and upvotes according to the category of user.
[Working on Mongo DB]

OUTPUT:

```
"Category": [{
    "id": "585a6ccc055f93cbb10bd179",
    "upvotes": [{
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
    }, {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
    }],
    "downvotes": [{
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
    }, {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
    }]
}]
```

Comment: When you say I want to show downvotes and upvotes you mean the number of upvotes and downvotes? Also: does the id in upvotes/downvotes play any rol? It would be great if you provide an example of your expected result

Comment: I want to show Name of the list of upvotes and downVotes feeds which is belongs to user category_ids

Comment: Indeed it would be great if you could use the [edit] link to update your question and show the code for the expected JSON result.

Comment: I have stored "id" of feeds into upvotes and downvotes array and fetching above detail by applying relation between them.